# java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

There are plenty of discussion about what it means and what to do about it, however the main solution of using `@NonCPS` doesn't seem to work.  Here's the relevant piece of the code:

```
@NonCPS
def restCall(String method, String resource, String data = '') {
    def URL url = new URL("${Params.REST_BASE_URI}/${resource}")
    def HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'restful-api', passwordVariable: 'RA_PASS', usernameVariable: 'RA_USER')]) {
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("${env.RA_USER}:${env.RA_PASS}").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${encoded}");
    }

    connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestMethod(method)
    connection.doOutput = true

    if (data != '') {
        def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)
        writer.write(data)
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()
    }

    connection.connect();

    def statusCode =  connection.responseCode
    if (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 201) {
        throw new Exception(connection.getErrorSteam().text)
    }

    return connection.content.text
}
```

Note that it does have `@NonCPS` on the function.  However executing this still produces the same error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field groovy.lang.Reference.value
    in object groovy.lang.Reference@1375b00
    in field WorkflowScript$_bitbucketCall_closure1.connection
    in object WorkflowScript$_bitbucketCall_closure1@b3001c
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@144b2a6
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@144b2a6
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at ...
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Marking the method as `@NonCPS` would only apply to the method itself I would think. That would then not apply to the scope of `URL.openConnection()`, which does not seem to be serializable. That being said, I hope someone knows how to solve this because global vars to create REST API calls are going to be rather helpful in jenkins-pipeline.

Comment: What I can see is that you’re calling some pipeline methods from within the NonCPS method. That’s neither supported or will work. However I think that the reason for the exception is not to search here but in the remaining code which is not marked as NonCPS. To support you there please submit the calling code as well.

Comment: @I don't think calling code has anything to do with it, as the stacktrace points to `HTTPUrlConnection` class.  In any event, an example calling code would be `def result = restCall('GET', 'info')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out, the `@NonCPS` annotation isn't needed to achieve what I'm after.  Instead, all I need to do is to ensure that the there are no non-serializable variables still initialised at the end of the method call.  Therefore the following method works fine:

```
def restCall(String method, String resource, String data = '') {
    def URL url = new URL("${Params.REST_BASE_URI}/${resource}")
    def HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'restful-api', passwordVariable: 'RA_PASS', usernameVariable: 'RA_USER')]) {
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("${env.RA_USER}:${env.RA_PASS}").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${encoded}");
    }

    connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestMethod(method)
    connection.doOutput = true

    if (data != '') {
        def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)
        writer.write(data)
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()
    }

    connection.connect();

    def statusCode =  connection.responseCode
    if (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 201) {
        String text = connection.getErrorStream().text
        connection = null
        throw new Exception(text)
    }

    String text = connection.content.text
    connection = null
}
```

The trick is to explicitly set `connection = null` before the end of the execution of the method.

Comment: This Q&A is from several years ago, but by any chance, do you know/do you have access to the version of Jenkins you used? I am facing the exact same issue, and eagerly tried your solution, but I _still_ get the `NotSerializableException`. I've literally copy/pasted the `restCall()` function from your answer verbatim into my Jenkins shared lib, and called `my_shared_lib.restCall(...)`, but the exception still occurs. I'm using Jenkins server version 2.222.3, which has Groovy version 2.4.12. Do you think the Jenkins/Groovy versions are relevant?

Comment: @StoneThrow
Same for me on Jenkins 2.289.1:
`...Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`
Any luck finding a solution for this problem?

Comment: After some testing I found out that if you remove the Jenkins step `withCredentials` from above code it will work again. Putting that step into the caller function worked fine for me.